When I read() a new frame from a cv2.VideoCapture, I get an old frame
When I wait a little between two calls of read() from a OpenCV VideoCapture device, I still seem to get an "old" frame, instead of what is seen by the camera at that point:
import cv2, time
    
vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
cv2.imshow("frame 1", frame)

time.sleep(10)

ret, frame2 = vid_capture.read()
cv2.imshow("frame 2", frame2)

while True:
    ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("feed", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

The code above shows two frames and the feed. The two frames are the same, while they shouldn't be (I moved the camera to make sure).
Does OpenCV do some buffering, and how can I wait a little before fetching a new frame?

Does this answer your question? OpenCV real time streaming video capture is slow. How to drop frames or get synced with real time?

I am no expert on video, but out of curiosity, why did you use time.sleep(10) rather than cv2.waitKey() for the equivalent time.

same or similar? don't say "same" if they aren't the same -- frames are buffered. frames are made by the camera at regular intervals, not when you ask for them. sleeping will only make the situation worse. you must not sleep. you must keep reading. frames don't disappear. the camera makes them. you must read them. it's always the same principle. spawn a thread, use it for reading, keep the latest frame, use it. https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40

time.sleep() or waitKey() here makes exactly no difference to VideoCapture. only difference is that waitKey() does event processing, keeping the GUI responsive, which isn't the issue here.

@toyotaSupra your comment makes no sense at all. OP made no claims as to the number of cameras on the system. nor is that the issue.

@ChristophRackwitz I think your comment is the answer. The duplicate mentioned does indeed explain it all a little better, but it also has way more information than the problem I was facing. I think for future visitors, having your answer on this question would be better.

@fmw42 because the naive me thought "I just want to wait a little", not "I need to get a key"

@Bart Friederichs. FYI cv2.waitKey(X) with a number for X is just a timer.

it does GUI event processing. without it, the GUI freezes.
